# How to connect harness cable to male pins of Raspberry pi

Tags: hardware, sensor, connectors

I have a `raspberry pi` and omron sensor `d6t`. This sensor comes with connector in which you can connect harness cable to it. It looks like below:

[image]

For my development purpose I connect the wires from sensor cable to breadboard and the from breadboard I connected it to raspberry pi male pins using male to female jumper wires. Now my development work in complete and I need to present this. So I am looking for some type of connector which can be directly connected to male pings of pi. But I am unable to find this online. Initially I thought the wires from the harness cable can be connected to [frc connector](https://rarecomponents.com/store/image/cache/data/0-1937-1-500x500.jpg) but I am not sure if this can work.

Can anyone please suggest some good solution for this. Please help. Thanks

Comment: Du-pont jumper cables are readily available on ebay and in many retailers. Whether these will attach to your device is impossible to say. You are unlikely to find any ready made connector - and you haven't specified what pins you want to use. If not you will need to cut and solder to the existing.

Comment: @Milliways This sensor is connected to 2,3,5,9 pins of the pi.

Comment: You can use a `lever connector` in combination with the Du-pont jumper cables to connect 2 wires without soldering.

Comment: @Swedgin Can you please share the link to image of level connector. Please thanks

Comment: @SAndrew Something like this: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/n8gLG6c-iKc/maxresdefault.jpg . So eg. WAGO 221 connectors

Comment: @Swedgin Got it Thanks. So basically what you are saying is that I should connect the wire from the harness cable into the level connector and then this level connector can be inserted into the male pin of pi. Is this correct.?

Comment: @Swedgin Okay I think I got it wrong. femal jumper will be isntalled on pi pins and other end of the jumper along with the wire of the harness cable will go into level connector.?

Comment: Yes indeed. Your second comment is correct. Also note that it's `leveR` and not `leveL` since it has a lever mechanism. I'll make this comment in an answer in a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't really a connector to connect those cables to the male pins on your RPi. A common solderless method is using lever connectors like the `WAGO 221` series.

[image]

You use a female-to-male Du-pont jumper cable from the RPi to the lever connector, and connect one of the wires fo the sensor to the other hole on the lever connector.